# Every compact Hausdorff space can be expressed as a disjoint union of finitely many open sets.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. 
Can we express as disjoint union of open sets ?

I got a proof for that.

Since $X$ is compact there exist a  finite sub collection of open sets $\{W_{i}\}_{i=1}^{n}$ that covers $X$.  Construct disjoint open sets $W_{i}'$ for $i=1, \cdots,n$ as follows :
\begin{eqnarray*}
W_{1}'= & W_{1} \\
W_{k}'= & W_{k}-\displaystyle \bigcup_{j=1}^{k-1}\overline{W_{j}'}'
\end{eqnarray*}

Then by the construction $W_{i}'$  are disjoint. 
Suppose $x \in W_{i}$ only then $x$ belongs to $W_{i}'$. Now let $x$ be an element of more than one $W_{i}$. Let $i$ be the least index for which $x \in W_{i}$ then  $x $ belongs to that $W_{i}'$  and does not belongs to any other $W_{j}'$. Thus the collection $\{ W_{i}' \}_{i=1}^{n}$ covers $X$.

Is this proof correct ? If it is other questions are immaterial. I know that I have not used Hausdorff condition in the proof.

Can we have a counter example ?

Can we apply some conditions on compact Hausdorff space so that it can be expressed as disjoint union of open sets ?

Comment: Your collection does not cover the whole space (try it with an interval). Also, you can just choose the whole space as a cover with just one set...

Comment: Just think about what this would say for bounded closed intervals.   It’s impossible.

Comment: Yes I understood the mistake in proof.

Comment: Look at "zero-dimensional" topological spaces.  You can get what you want there.  But a zero-dimensional topological space has a base of clopen sets, which introduces weirdness not found in a "typical" topology (like, it's totally disconnected).

Answer (score 6):

The result is far from being true.

No connected (compact Hausdorff) space can be expressed in this form (except in the trivial way in which there is only one  non-empty open set in the collection).

Comment: Not a good answer. You only use connectedness, which was not even mentioned in the OP.

Comment: @Klaus My intention is to provide a counter-examples.  OP can think of connected compact Hausdorff spaces to realize that the assertion is very very false. OP did ask for a counter-example, didn' t they?

Comment: I can see that, but then you might as well just remove "compact Hausdorff space" because it has nothing to do with it. Besides, you can always (trivially) do it with as many sets as you want as long as you take the empty set sufficiently often.

Answer (score 3):

You can always do it with $n=1$ and $W_1=X$: if $X$ is connected, this is the one and only possibility. Otherwise, your procedure fails in general, your error lying in the fact that $\{W_i',\:\, i\in\Bbb N\}$ may not be a covering. Also, the entire idea of a non-trivial case $n\ge2$ fails catastrophically: again, see the concept of *connected space*, and related concepts such as *connected components* of a topological space.

Answer (score 3):

If the unit disc, say, were a disjoint union of open sets, it would be disconnected.  Just split the open sets into two groups.  But it is not

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the trivial case $n=1$, your new set isn't a covering. Take $X=[0,1]$, $W_1=[0,3/4)$ and $W_2=(1/4,1]$. Then $W_2'=[1/4,1]\setminus[0,3/4]=(3/4,]$ so $3/4$ does not belong either to $W_1'$ or $W_2'$.

In general your result is false if the space is connected. Even if it is not connected, you cannot chose $n$ arbitrarily, it depends on the number of connected components of the space.